# Exclude Selenium test methods in C# test project using VSTS

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, build-definition

I have a Selenium test project which is checked into a VSTS repo and I am trying to create a scheduled build definition in VSTS to run a subset of the test functions contained in the built project assembly "SeleniumTest.dll".

As part of the build definition I have a VS Test task which looks like the following:

[image]

In an attempt to exclude all the test classes I do not want run, I have included the following runsettings file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- File name extension must be .runsettings -->
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>

            <Functions>  
              <Exclude>  
                <!-- Exclude methods in the SeleniumTests.Tests\ZoneTest: --> 
                <Function>SeleniumTests.Tests\.LoginTest\..*</Function>
                <Function>SeleniumTests.Tests\.ProfileTest\..*</Function>
              </Exclude>  
            </Functions>   

          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

I'm not sure if a runsettings file is the thing I need to achieve this. If not what apporach should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Visual Studio task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/releases/m109/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) include Test Filter criteria setting that can filter tests.

Allowed operators:

•   = implies an exact match

•   != imples an exact not match

•   ~ implies a contains lookup

More information: [TestCase filter](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md)

BTW, the runsettings file you provided is used for CodeCoverage instead of filter test to run.

Comment: I believe this is restricted to .NET CORE and .NETStandard projects. Unfortunately, my project is a traditional .NET Framework project. My last resort would be to convert the project to .NET CORE